# Preety Url: stop loading page with .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using pretty url for my project and it is working fine.

```
http://testurl.com/user/12345
```

I am using .htaccess for redirection.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ user.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Today i found if i change the link in browser like this `http://testurl.com/user.php` then page is also loading i want to show error message (Alert) if someone directly trying to access

Comment: OK, fine. But what is your question here? Looks like you simply need a `RewriteCond` and a redirection to an error page.

Comment: I just want error page to load for specific for this. user.php file is there but i don't want user to access that directly

Comment: There is little sense in repeating what you already wrote. You already use rewrite conditions and rules, so why cant you use them for that additional task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to add your error or redirect in the `user.php` without `id` query string.

But you also can add (after `RewriteBase /`):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain more. Voted Up

Comment: Explain what ? It's what you ask for. Error message (forbidden) when you directly use `user.php` without `id`

Comment: I got that. Thank you. Will test and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well solve your problem through code reorganization. I did this in one of my projects, and it has worked well.

## 1. When you create a pretty URL, move the according file into another directory

So, in this case, you had the URL `example.com/user.php?id=123` visible externally. Now, you want a pretty URL for it, e.g. `example.com/user/123`.

On file level, before you had

```
- user.php
```

I suggest you move that to another directory, where all scripts live which are accessed by pretty URL only:

```
- rewrites/
    |- user.php
```

## 2. Create redirects for your old URL to your new URL, externally

The same as you did above.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

## 3. Rewrite the new, pretty URL to moved script, internally

The same as you did above, with difference that the directory name `rewrites` is added.

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ rewrites/user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ rewrites/user.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

## 4. `example.com/user.php` now fails with a 404

Because `/user.php` does not exist anymore in the file system, it automatically fails with a 404 if called without params.

## 5. Benefits

This approach might sound like additional work for nothing, but these are the benefits making it worthwile in my opinion:

1. You do not need an additional `.htaccess` rule for error handling
2. You get better code organization
3. You get better overview of what is already accessible with pretty URL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.